# SQL Presentation

Tags: sql, presentation

In a 10 minute SQL presentation for beginners, which topics should I cover? (or functions)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not present a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic concept is CRUD.

**create**, **read**, **update**, **delete**.

Answer (score 0):

In 10 minutes? I would talk about the nature of relational databases how powerful they are (amount of data, speed of summarisation, ordering, joining etc, why Excel is [NOT A DATABASE!!!!.]

It really depends on what sort of audience. would-be devs? - Explain sets and the give them the anatomy of the `SELECT` statement

end-user? explain BI concepts and security benefits.